# Turning an array of strings into an array of numbers within the string

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings like this:

```
[ '[{"asnumber":0}',
  '{"asnumber":1}',
  '{"asnumber":2}',
  '{"asnumber":3}',
  '{"asnumber":4}',
  '{"asnumber":5}',
  '{"asnumber":6}',
  '{"asnumber":7}',
  '{"asnumber":8}',
  '{"asnumber":9}',
  '{"asnumber":10}',
  '{"asnumber":11}',
  '{"asnumber":12}',
  '{"asnumber":13}',
  '{"asnumber":14}',
  '{"asnumber":15}',
  '{"asnumber":16}',
  '{"asnumber":17}',
```

etc. How do I create an array of the numbers in each?

Comment: What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4PUDF/)?

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far to solve the problem? 2. Can you get this as an array of raw objects from the source instead of an array of (almost) Json-encoded objects as strings?

Comment: Well your numbers align perfectly with the array indices, so...

Comment: Oh well... assuming the last entry has the `]` at the end, you could do this: `JSON.parse(arr).map(function(o) { return o.asnumber; })`

Comment: @user3754317 want it as an answer to check it?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes please.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Please don't tell beginners to use `for-in` to iterate an Array. Seriously. Just don't.

Comment: @cookiemonster you're right, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to get the result you expect:

```
var arr = [ '[{"asnumber":0}',
  '{"asnumber":2}',
  '{"asnumber":4}',
  '{"asnumber":6}',
  '{"asnumber":8}',
  '{"asnumber":10}'];

var newArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    newArr.push(Number(arr[i].replace(/\D/g,'')));
}

console.log(newArr);
```

As @cookiemonster pointed, it will be good to left aside the `for...in` statement and use the good and old `for`. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4PUDF/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var stringArray = [
        '{"asnumber":1}',
        '{"asnumber":2}',
        '{"asnumber":3}',
        '{"asnumber":4}',
        '{"asnumber":5}',
        '{"asnumber":6}',
        '{"asnumber":7}',
    ];

var result = stringArray.map(function(x){
    var obj = JSON.parse(x);
    return obj ? obj.asnumber : null;
});

console.log(result);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: You modified the data to remove the `[`.

Comment: ok maybe a copy paste error? @user3754317 should the ``[`` placed in your string array? if so, i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var oldArray = ['{"asnumber":0}',
  '{"asnumber":1}',
  '{"asnumber":2}',
  '{"asnumber":3}',
  '{"asnumber":4}',
  '{"asnumber":5}',
  '{"asnumber":6}',
  '{"asnumber":7}',
  '{"asnumber":8}',
  '{"asnumber":9}',
  '{"asnumber":10}',
  '{"asnumber":11}',
  '{"asnumber":12}',
  '{"asnumber":13}',
  '{"asnumber":14}',
  '{"asnumber":15}',
  '{"asnumber":16}',
  '{"asnumber":17}'],
  newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach(function (element) { newArray.push(JSON.parse(element).asnumber); });
```